# changing stack's top pointer by passing by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

I am trying to change the top pointer of stack.

1) Directly changing the pointer is working correctly. and passed pointer is changed accordingly.

```
root = root -> next;
```

2) But on dereferencing the pointer then changing it locally is not changing the pointer.

```
Node* root = *top;
root = root -> next
```

function definition:

```
int pop(Node** top)
{
    if(isEmpty(*top))
        return -1;  

    Node* temp = *top
    int popped_data = temp-> data;

    Node* root = *top;
    //root = root -> next; // This is not modifying the actual pointer passed
    *top = (*top)->next; // This is working fine. top is changed

    delete temp;
    return popped_data;
}
```

Comment: So, is this for academic learning purposes or is there some other reason not to use a C++ standard container instead?

Answer (score 0):

By this you are making a copy of a pointer

```
Node* root = *top;
```

and following

```
root = root->next;
```

modifies this copy.

You can use reference to pointer instead:

```
Node *&root= *top;
```

Comment: How come then actual value is getting changed here by creating a copy pointer then changing the value.
Actual value is getting changed.


void changeByCopy(int *i)
{
  int *j = i;
  *j = 20;
}

Comment: same way I should be able to  change pointer to pointer. Copy then change it.

To change i am passing i's pointer then changing is by creating a copy pointer. Same way to change node pointer I am passing pointer of this node pointer then change is by creating a copy pointer.

Comment: @user3990393 in your case you can't change `top`, but you can change `*top`.

Comment: @user3990393 in the comment you don't change `i`, you change `*i`.